# Angular REST returning Syntax error on JSON parse

Tags: angularjs, rest

I am getting an error "syntax error JSON parse unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of json data".  The RESTful service is runnning, a straight test returns valid json data (verified at http://jsonlint.com/)

```
     [{"id":2,"name":"Flourescent Penetrant Inspection","description":"The fluorescent penetrant inspection process.","abbreviation":"FPI","tempId":null,"processType":"INSPECTION","indicationTypes":[{"id":1,"name":"Crack","description":"An identified crack on the piece.","abbreviation":"","tempId":null,"groupName":"","markupType":"LINE","useSizeDescription":true,"sizeDescription":"<= 1 in.::> 1 in.","rejectReason":"Crack","defaultDisposition":"MRB"},{"id":2,"name":"Inclusion","description":"An identified inclusion on the piece.","abbreviation":"","tempId":null,"groupName":"","markupType":"DOT","useSizeDescription":false,"sizeDescription":"","rejectReason":"Inclusion","defaultDisposition":"REWORK"}]},{"id":4,"name":"CMM","description":"The CMM process.","abbreviation":"CMM","tempId":null,"processType":"INSPECTION","indicationTypes":[]}]
```

The error in the HTTP response, yet it is returning a 200 message.  The angular app is seeing it as an empty array.  Any ideas?

The applicable part of the Controller is:

```
    indicationTypeController.constant("indicationTypeUrl", "http://localhost:8080/services/api/indication-types.json");

indicationTypeController.controller('indicationTypeController', function ($scope, $http, $resource, indicationTypeUrl) {

    $scope.indicationTypeResource = $resource(indicationTypeUrl+":id", { id: "@id" },
        { 'create': {method: "POST"}, 'update': {method: "PUT"}
        });

    $scope.listIndicationTypes = function () {
        $http.get(indicationTypeUrl)
            .success(function(data){
                $scope.indicationTypes = data;
            });

        //$scope.indicationTypes = $scope.indicationTypeResource.query();

    }
      . . . .
```

As you can see I am currently using a $http.get, I also tried a query().

Any

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, the $http promise returns an object that contains the headers and the data.  In your success handler for the $http, you have

```
    $http.get(indicationTypeUrl)
        .success(function(data){
            $scope.indicationTypes = data;
        });
```

I'm pretty sure that `data` is the full response and you need to get the specific data by using the `data` property of this object.  Therefore, this would become the following:

```
    $http.get(indicationTypeUrl)
        .success(function(data){
            $scope.indicationTypes = data.data;
        });
```

In other implementations, instead of the passed in parameter being called `data`, it's usually called `result`, so that you can reference the contained data like `result.data` instead of `data.data`

The other thing to make sure of is that the `Content-Type` is set appropriately between the server and client.  If it's not `application\json` you'll probably run into issues.

Comment: The problem turned out to be a CORS issue, but what threw me off was no CORS error message.  What it was is that the system was returning a CORS error message, but since it wasn't a JSON array, we were getting that error message instead.  Your suggestion made me look harder at what was being returned, at that did the trick.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is an CORS issue, please add the following to the response header, before sending the result.

> **"Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*"**

For instance, if you are using play server (Java code) to serve the request, the following statement should be added to the method where you are returning the data from

> **response().setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");**